# K&R 1-20 Solution

Tags: c, strings, io, formatting

I'm currently reading the infamous K&R C book and trying to solve Exercise 1-20. My solution looks kind of too simple, but it works. I've searched the web for different solutions, but they all are much longer, although I didn't see any improvement compared to my code. Do you see anything which might compromise my approach? The exercise is as follows:

> Write a program detab that replaces tabs in the input with the proper number of blanks to space to the next tab stop. Assume a fixed set of tab stops, say every n columns. Should n be a variable or a symbolic parameter?

And here's my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define COLS 8

int main (void)
{
    int ch;
    int charCounter = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (ch != '\t'){
            putchar(ch);
            charCounter++;
        }

        if (ch == '\t'){
            for (int i = 0; i < (COLS - (charCounter % COLS)); ++i) {
                putchar(' ');
            }
            charCounter = 0;
        }

        if (ch == '\n'){
            charCounter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Do you see anything which might compromise my approach?

1. Good use of `int ch;` as the type returned by `fgetc()` is `int` and not `char` - avoided a [rookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rookie) mistake.
2. The `if()` layout looks weak.  Suggest using `else`

   ```
   // current
   if (condition) {
   }
   if (!condition) {
   }

   // Suggest
   if (condition) {
   }
   else {
   }
   ```
3. It is easier for people to understand `==` rather than `!=`.  This is important for writing the correct code and maintaining it.  So, when practical, avoid negation.  Don't you think it is not a bit mis-understandable to negate the inverse of a sentence, No?

   ```
   if (ch == '\t') {
     for (int i = 0; i < (COLS - (charCounter % COLS)); ++i) {
       putchar(' ');
     }
     charCounter = 0;
   } else {
     putchar(ch);
     charCounter++;
   }
   ```
4. The `if (ch == '\n')` is only possible when `ch != '\t'`.  But this is minor.  In a more complex code having this `if()` stand alone may be preferable.

   ```
   ...
   } else {
     putchar(ch);
     charCounter++;
     if (ch == '\n') {
       charCounter = 0;
     }
   }
   ```
5. Then there is the missing `return _something_;`.  With `main()`, lack  of a return in the end will inject a `return 0;`.  Should you do this or not is a *coding style*.  One side says, no.  Minimal code.  The other side says - yes.  Be explicit, it is poor practice to omit.  The larger point here is that some "do/don't do" axioms are driven by your group's coding style.  Following a consistent style is more important than being "right".  If your group lacks a coding style, create one.  This applies to all sorts of indentation, brackets or not, `++i` or `i++` issues.
6. Pedantic code would avoid integer overflow from pathological long lines.  Example:

   ```
    // charCounter++;
    charCounter = (charCounter + 1)%COLS;

    // i < (COLS - (charCounter % COLS)_;
    i < (COLS - charCounter);
   ```
7. Clerical: Since the design document is "K&R C,  Exercise 1-20.", that information should have been in code.  Name and date is nice.  It is your work, proudly sign it,

   ```
   /* K&R C,  Exercise 1-20. */
   /* Saalim  2016 Apr 5 */

   #include <stdio.h>
   ...
   ```

> Should `n` be a variable or a symbolic parameter?

A more advance code would code some means to pass in a variable rather than a fixed tab stop of 8.

Very good initial post.